# Java --- How to handle deserializing an unknown-number of byte[]? - Java

Tags: java, serialization, byte

One program is serializing `byte[]`'s to be sent to the user of the next program. This user will not know how many objects are being sent.

Is there a way to find out how many objects have been serialized from the `ObjectInputStream`?

Or would the best solution be to continue reading the objects and catch the exception when it is thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to `write` first into your `ObjectOutputStream`, the `total amount of objects` to be read

Comment: Bahaha! Wow I can't believe I didn't think of that. EDIT: just out of curiosity, if not using this method, is there an alternative to actually find out from an unknown stream?

Comment: @MitchWeaver I don't believe so other approaches would be simply incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Just have the receiver read until it catches an `EOFException`.

Answer (score 0):

Found what I believe to be the east way, just add all the objects into a `container`, and then save the `container`.

Then when `deserializing`, you now have the `container` of objects which you can call `.size()` or `.length()`